# C# Source Generator diagnostic documentation page link

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I've written a Source generator which creates an error, I would love to be able to give the user more information about the specific error that they have by going to a documentation page.

Luckily [DiagnosticDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnosticdescriptor.-ctor?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticDescriptor.%2523ctor)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0) has a `helpLinkUri` field which is described as:

> An optional hyperlink that provides a more detailed description regarding the diagnostic.

But when I try to use this by setting `helpLinkUri` to a test website like `google.com`, `http://google.com`, `https://google.com` or `www.google.com` I instead get sent to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/not-in-toc/default which isn't what I set. This is when using Visual Studio and clicking on the error code in the errors panel.

How do I open a custom webpage for source generator diagnostic? Are there any limitations that the documentation doesn't mention? Is this a limitation present inside Visual Studio?

CodeExample:

```
private static void ErrorMessage(SourceProductionContext _arg1, AttributeSourceWithContext _arg2)
{
    DiagnosticDescriptor errorType = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
        id: "Error1",
        title: "Incorrect line",
        messageFormat: "This is complex, open help link for good explanation",
        helpLinkUri: "google.com", // <----- this is not opened when inspecting the error
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    Diagnostic errorInstance = Diagnostic.Create(errorType, _arg2.GetLocation());
    _arg1.ReportDiagnostic(errorInstance);
}
```

Comment: Can you share more information about the inaccurate redirection of your target page? For example, the key code of this module.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT I don't understand the question. If I give the help url of `Google.com` and I open the help for the error I get sent to the microsoft website in the question not the site that I indicated as having help information for the error.

Comment: This page will only pop up after the program runs wrong. According to your description, there may be a problem with the code. Can share some of your code?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT it's not during execution, I want the page to open when I double click the error message in Visual Studios "Error List" pane. If you click the error code "Error1" (in the example) I would expect the browser to open to "google.com" as per example but it doesn't. This is my code as it's a custom code generator so I would expect to be able to direct to my own domain not MSDN.

Comment: I'm seeing the same misbehavior. My code generator is interested in attributes that decorate enum members. If my CG diagnoses a malformed attribute, a red or blue squiggle appears under the attribute, as expected. If the user hovers over the squiggle, a tooltip appears with the expected diagnostic text (ID and description) from the DiagnosticDescriptor, e.g., "AS101 The foo attribute is messed up." If the descriptor's helpLinkUri specifies a URI, AS101 would be a link in the tooltip and WOULD navigate to the expected site. But AS101 in the Error List panel would navigate to the MS site.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Also one where the link would be written in the Description column after the message. Where if you clicked on it, Visual Studio would crash.

As you may know working with Source Generators in Visual Studio, they don't always behave as coded.

Not to fear -

> Try cleaning your solution, build, restart Visual Studio, and then
> rebuild your solution.

These are the four horsemen of coding Source Generators.

The first time you build or rebuild, some sort of cache of the generator will happen.

You can sometimes notice this, if you start coding and edit a LiteralString value in the generator, the change in the final document will not always happen right away.

However, editing in the file targeted by the generator, will change the final result almost instantly - when the generator works of course.

In the end i got it to work with:

```
new DiagnosticDescriptor(
    "ErrorCodeXXXX", 
    "Dumb code title", 
    "The code right here is dumb and dont always work as intended.", 
    "DumbFeatureError", 
    DiagnosticSeverity.Error, 
    true, 
    helpLinkUri: "https://DocLink.Domain/InternalDoc")
```

Edit:
Now that i look at your code again , it might also be because you dont have "https://" in your URL.

Comment: I mentioned the styles of domain that I tried above the code example which includes the `https://` prefix so I don't think that's the fix. It might be that the a VS update has fixed it? I used 17.4.5

Comment: I dont know about any update. I can only say that i had the same problem(and others), but after "cleaning, building, restarting and rebuilding" then it worked for me.